# udev rule not working when plugging in USB printer

Tags: ubuntu, usb, udev

I'm trying to run a script when a USB printer is plugged in on Ubuntu.

Based on [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1290438) link, I tried to create a udev rule for every usb devices being plugged in.

As instructed I created the rule file with the following content

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="sd??", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USB %k"
```

And then the script in the above path

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello World!' >>"/home/<username>/Desktop/udev.out"
exit
```

When I plug in my pen drive, indeed the udev.out file appears. Unfortunately, when I plug in a printer via USB, regardless of which door I use. the event simply doesn't trigger.

Is there anything I'm missing? or a different behaviour for different USB types?

Thanks in advance

I have also followed [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284224/autorun-a-script-after-i-plugged-or-unplugged-a-usb-device) steps to no avail

Comment: Run `lsusb` to get vendor and product ID of your printer. then use the latter link to create a rule.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, I think the `KERNEL=="sd??"` would only match devices that create a device whose name has the form `/dev/sd*`.  I suspect your printer does not create such a device because it is a printer, not a disk drive.  You should try removing the `KERNEL=="sd??"` part from your rule.